# How can i optimize this mysql query having no repeation of keywords and ips?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
COUNT(keywords) AS count_keywords 
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM keyword_searches GROUP BY keywords, ip
) tmp_table 
 WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2012-03-31 00:00:00' AND '2015-03-31 23:59:59';
```

How can i optimize this query?

Comment: So you mean you want to get the records where there is only one value per group `keywords, ip` and with the given date range ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you filter record using `where` condition in inner query and then you count `keywords` in outer query.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(keywords) AS count_keywords 
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM keyword_searches WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2012-03-31 00:00:00' AND '2015-03-31 23:59:59' GROUP BY keywords, ip
) tmp_table ;
```

In your case you got all records which is not satisfy condition `BETWEEN '2012-03-31 00:00:00' AND '2015-03-31 23:59:59'`